# The voltage reduced variation of battery in the electrical appliances we used

Tags: voltage, batteries

There are lots of battery in our electrical appliances,for example,laptop, remote control and mosquito swatter,etc.As we know,the battery we used can be a voltage source in that appliance,that is, a VDC in our IC simulation.Normally,our VDC almost doesn't reduce,ignore 10% error,but the battery voltage will reduce with the time we used.So i am a little confused with the voltage reduced variation of battery.I will provide two possible situation for the voltage reduced variation of battery,but i don't know which is right.

Set the battery is 1.8V for full charged,and can use for 10 hours.

1.The voltage reduced variation and time are almost linear decrement,that is ,if the voltage will reduce 0.18V/1 hour,then after 1 hour,the voltage should be 1.62V ,and the voltage should be 0V after used for 10 hours.

2.The voltage will be a constant,almost 1.8,for using 10 hours,but after 10 hours,the voltage will reduce rapidly,but won't reduce to 0V,take 0.5V for example,and 0.5V can't provide(active) the IC in the electrical appliances,so we say the battery is dead.

Comment: Have you looked at the datasheet?

Comment: So the voltage reduced variation depends on different battery?

Comment: Different battery chemistries have different characteristics. See the datasheets for details.

Comment: Closer to (2) than (1) but somewhere between them. And yes it depends on the battery.